# Anacondaをインストーラーからバージョンアップできるか？

Tags: python, windows, anaconda

今、WindowsでAnacondaの再インストールしているのですが、
再インストールの作業中に、気になる事があり、[このサイト](https://qiita.com/t2y/items/2a3eb58103e85d8064b6)を調べてもわからなかったので質問させていただきます。

Windowsで古いバージョンのAnacondaがインストールされている状態で、
新しいバージョンのAnacondaをインストールすると、Anacondaのバージョンは更新されますか？

Comment: Anaconda Navigaterからもバージョンアップできますが、それとは違うという事でしょうか?　要注意が、管理者権限無いと意味不明なメッセージが出てきます。

Comment: はい。そのとおりです。インストーラーを使ったバージョンアップです。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

一旦、削除(アンインストール)してから、再インストールすべきと思います。
私もあまり詳しくないですが、古いバージョンだとインストールされる場所が違うとか、トラブルの元になる事があります。(以前、一週間ほど、悩み、再インストール)

Comment: これで解決しました。いずれにせよ、再インストールするしかないんですね。ありがとうございました。